# Find Methods/Properties Missing Javadocs Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, comments, javadoc

I'm wanting to properly document all of my code for a class assignment, however at times I forget to add the Javadoc comments as I'm coding. I was wondering, is there some way in Android Studio to easily locate methods and properties that have not received a Javadoc comment yet?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out a regular expression that basically serves the purpose of finding undocumented code:

```
[^\*/]\n\s+(public|private|protected)
```

It will find any line starting with public/private/protected (which is how methods and properties usually start), as long as that line does not have the end of a comment before it.
The regex isn't perfect - it might give some false positives - but it works.